# Firebase Analytics Active User not counting

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9.2 . In my Firebase Debug view(Firebase web) I found its working as expected and respond according to my device . But in Dashboard still it shows that user count is zero. In GoogleInfo.plist file  analytics is already enabled (check Screenshot).

[ScreenShot of Firebase web dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDnDh.jpg)

My Xcode Console logs:

```
2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.404190 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789229] TIC Read Status[1: 0x0]: 1: 57
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.404623 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789229] TIC Read Status[1: 0x0]: 1: 57
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.457635 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v .40009000 started
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.458067 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023008] To disable debug logging set the following application argument: -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled(see Link)
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.458967 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023009] Debug logging enabled
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.576031 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789229] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS003007] Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically.To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.668492 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS029014] Successfully parsed a configuration.Version: 1519621177783434
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.669028 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023016] Firebase Analytics is ready to receive events
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.687974 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023080] Setting user property.Name, value: first_open_after_install(_fi), 1
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.725633 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023087] User property set.Name, value: first_open_after_install(_fi), 1
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.760954 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked.Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.804128 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023024] No data to upload.Upload task will not be scheduled
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.804859 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS033003] Scheduling user engagement timer
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.825001 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002002] Engagement timer scheduled to fire in approx.(s): 3600
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.825689 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.826152 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: app, MenuUIViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.828751 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled.Marking event as debug and real - time.Event name, parameters: MenuUIViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.897541 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023072] Event logged.Event name, event params: MenuUIViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.914332 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx.(s): -0.2236000299453735
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.914481 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx.(s): -0.2236000299453735
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.916610 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: app, MenuViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.918135 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled.Marking event as debug and real - time.Event name, parameters: MenuViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.940231 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023072] Event logged.Event name, event params: MenuViewController, {
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.953185 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023027] Do not schedule an upload task.Task already exists.Will be executed in seconds: -0.262964129447937
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.954948 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023051] Logging event: origin, name, params: auto, screen_view(_vs), {
  firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MenuViewController;
  firebase_screen_id(_si) = 752457106184608269;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = auto;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.957701 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023073] Debug mode is enabled.Marking event as debug and real - time.Event name, parameters: screen_view(_vs), {
  firebase_screen_id(_si) = 752457106184608269;
  firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MenuViewController;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = auto;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 51.977333 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023072] Event logged.Event name, event params: screen_view(_vs), {
  firebase_screen_id(_si) = 752457106184608269;
  firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MenuViewController;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = auto;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.006604 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023027] Do not schedule an upload task.Task already exists.Will be executed in seconds: -0.3142800331115723
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.007656 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002001] Measurement timer fired
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.007740 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.008014 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023033] Starting data upload
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.015685 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023105] Event is not subject to real - time event count daily limit.Marking an event as real - time.Event name, parameters: MenuUIViewController, {
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.021005 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023105] Event is not subject to real - time event count daily limit.Marking an event as real - time.Event name, parameters: MenuViewController, {
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = app;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.023488 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023105] Event is not subject to real - time event count daily limit.Marking an event as real - time.Event name, parameters: screen_view(_vs), {
  firebase_screen_id(_si) = 752457106184608269;
  firebase_screen_class(_sc) = MenuViewController;
  firebase_realtime(_r) = 1;
  firebase_debug(_dbg) = 1;
  firebase_event_origin(_o) = auto;
 }
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.026790 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS012018] Saving bundle.size(bytes): 442
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.027669 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023116] Bundle added to the upload queue.BundleID, timestamp(ms): 15, 1519627010924
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.047849 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023038] Uploading events.Elapsed time since last successful upload(s): 349.1903488636017
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.049981 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023039] Measurement data sent to network.Timestamp(ms), data: 1519627012046, < FIRAPBMeasurementBatch: 0x106f75ec0 >
  2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 52.059572 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS900000] Uploading data.Host: https: //app-measurement.com/a
  2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.694292 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789219] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS901006] Received SSL challenge
 for host.Host: https: //app-measurement.com/a
  2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.897931 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] TIC Read Status[4: 0x0]: 1: 57
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.898099 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789231] TIC Read Status[4: 0x0]: 1: 57
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.900632 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023044] Successful upload.Got network response.Code, size: 204, -1
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.911832 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002002] Measurement timer scheduled to fire in approx.(s): -6.986776947975159
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.913858 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023028] Upload task scheduled to be executed in approx.(s): -6.986776947975159
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.942578 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS023024] No data to upload.Upload task will not be scheduled
 2018 - 02 - 26 12: 36: 58.942804 + 0600 AppG App[5182: 2789221] 4.9 .0 - [Firebase / Analytics][I - ACS002003] Measurement timer canceled
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are using Debug Mode which will display test users in real-time. However, the active user panel is for Stream-view which is not guaranteed to be in real-time but in the past 30 minutes. Therefore, it might display the number of active users after several minutes to 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. If you don't mind , can you please share any official reference about it ?  Actually, my android application   working fine and always display the number of real time users. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think this is the most relevant I could find: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en. The screenshot you provided also has a button to go to StreamView on the bottom of the card.